# Rounding Up to the nearest 0.5

Tags: javascript, rounding

I am trying to round a number up to the nearest 0.5.
For example:

```
0.1 -> 0.5
0.5 -> 0.5
0.6 -> 1
1 -> 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: `return Math.ceil(num*2)/2;`